# Get data from JSON Object by using path

Tags: javascript, json, jsonpath

Suppose I have a JSON Object like this:

```
var data = {
    "name": "abcd",
    "age": 21,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "88 8nd Street",
        "city": "New York"
    },
    "phoneNumber": [
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "111 111-1111"
        },
        {
            "type": "fax",
            "number": "222 222-2222"
        }
    ]
}
```

and I want to get the information from this json object by using path which is a string, like

```
var age = 'data/age'; // this path should return age
var cityPath = 'data/address/city'; // this path should return city
var faxNumber = 'data/phoneNumber/1/number'; // this path should return fax number
```

Is there any way I can get this information from the string path? Currently I am splitting the path by `/` and then using it like `data.age` or `data.address.city`. But this approach is not useful for any array contained in JSON object.

Is there any better and optimal approach in JavaScript for this problem?

Comment: JSON is a string format of a JavaScript object. You do not have a JSON "object".

Comment: the dup target uses `.` as separator you should use `/` for your use case

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can access the data from the JSON, no need to use paths:

```js
var data = {
    "name": "abcd",
    "age": 21,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "88 8nd Street",
        "city": "New York"
    },
    "phoneNumber": [
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "111 111-1111"
        },
        {
            "type": "fax",
            "number": "222 222-2222"
        }
    ]
}

var age = data.age;
var cityPath = data.address.city;
var faxNumber = data.phoneNumber[0].number; // array first item begins with 0

console.log({age, cityPath, faxNumber})
```

If you really need to use paths for some reason, I suggest using lodash `get` method https://lodash.com/docs#get